# JetBrains Rider IDE fails to debug C# .NET Core unit tests with "CLR load callback is already in error state" error

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm running JetBrains Rider 2020.3.2 and am attempting to debug into some .NET Core `Xunit` C# unit tests. Specifically, I have the following .NET versions installed:

[image]

Interestingly, when running the unit tests (without debugging), they run correctly. However, when attempting to debug them, I'm seeing the following error:

> One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (CLR load callback is already in error state. Value does not fall within the expected range. The error code is COR_E_ARGUMENT, or E_INVALIDARG, or WIN32_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, or 0x80070057.))

I have researched this error and come up with the following potential remedies:

[image]

(Source: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/06/16/rider-eap-23-net-core-debugger-back-code-cleanup/)

But this advice was written many years ago, and I do have the latest version of .NET Core.

How can I get my unit tests to be debuggable?

Comment: This YouTrack issue seems to be related, but there is no solution yet:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-66129